# How can I show this Toast message only if I click the second Tab?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, tabs, toast

I have a navigation bar with three tabs each tab is a Fragment.
I wrote in the onCreateView method of my second fragment this toast message:

```
public class SecondFragment extends Fragment{

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.second_layout,container,false);


        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Test", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        return rootView;
    }
```

What I want is that only if I click this tab the message displays.
But the problem is that if I start the application the message displays directly, but why?

Here is my MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    NavigationView mNavigationView;
    FragmentManager mFragmentManager;
    FragmentTransaction mFragmentTransaction;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        /**
         *Setup the DrawerLayout and NavigationView
         */

        mNavigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.shitstuff) ;

        /**
         * Lets inflate the very first fragment
         * Here , we are inflating the TabFragment as the first Fragment
         */

        mFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        mFragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        mFragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView,new TabFragment()).commit();

    }


}
```

And (I think this is Important for this question) my TabFragment:

```
public class TabFragment extends Fragment {
    public static TabLayout tabLayout;
    public static ViewPager viewPager;
    public static int int_items = 3 ;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {



        /**
         *Inflate tab_layout and setup Views.
         */
            View x =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_layout,null);
            tabLayout = (TabLayout) x.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
            viewPager = (ViewPager) x.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

        /**
         *Set an Apater for the View Pager
         */
        viewPager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(getChildFragmentManager()));

        /**
         * Now , this is a workaround ,
         * The setupWithViewPager dose't works without the runnable .
         * Maybe a Support Library Bug .
         */

        tabLayout.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
                   }
        });

        return x;

    }

    class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        /**
         * Return fragment with respect to Position .
         */

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position)
        {

            if(position == 0){
                return new FirstFragment();
            }
            if(position == 1){
                return new SecondFragment();
            }
            if(position == 2){
                return new ThirdFragment();
            }

        return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {

            return int_items;

        }

        /**
         * This method returns the title of the tab according to the position.
         */

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

            switch (position){
                case 0 :
                    return "First";
                case 1 :
                    return "Second";
                case 2 :
                    return "Third";
            }
                return null;
        }
    }

}
```

So where do I have to say `Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Test", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();` to display it only by pressing on the second tab?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code for terminating the toast once it is shown so that it will not be visible when you click on another fragment.

**try this one**

```
toast = new Toast(getContext());
toast.cancel(); //this will prevent toast from displaying multiple times
```

Hope it will work

Comment: I asked this question with the Toast example. But actually I want to display my Interstitial when I click on the second tab, this is why I need to know where to write that line.

Answer (score 0):

Wait! if you have multiple tabs then each tabs must be containing individual fragment and for each fragment there is java class and a layout file for the same then the coding part will be inside onCreate method of java file and xml/layout part will be in .xml file thats it.